# form validation - make sure at least 1 checkbox is selected

Tags: php

I am having trouble with form validation for checkboxes.

Here is the checkbox code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="defect[]" value="{$ng_id}">
    </div>
</div>
```

If I just do something like this then it echo's out whatever I select.

```
foreach($_POST['defect'] as $defects) {
echo $defects;
}
```

I have tried to use the empty function on its own as well as this:

```
if(empty($defects) || count($defects) < 1) {
```

but I just keep getting the error:

> Undefined index: defect

Comment: `$defects=$_POST['defect']; foreach($defects as $defect){ ...` this is the correct way to access the array contained inside the `$_POST['defect']`

Comment: checkboxes don't use `empty()`, they use `isset()`.

Comment: and where's the form for this or how are you handling "POST"?

Comment: `value="{$ng_id}"` that seems to be angular-related.

Comment: well, if you left the question, you'll either have to ping one of us, or see the answers given.

Comment: @ Fred, no it isn't angular. It is the way I put php variables into code using heredoc.

Comment: @Jonathan you didn't ping correctly (as I did for you here); my member name is distinctive. I only saw this because I still had the tab opened (by accident). well, you have more code than you posted. Again, see the answers below. I have my own thoughts on this, but seeing that I don't know which animal(s) we're really dealing with here, I am hesitant to keep going or posting an answer. Good luck, sincerely.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is that when you do not select any of checkboxes, no variable named `defect` is sent. Simply create hidden field before any checkbox with empty value to always send it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="defect[]" value="">
```

And in PHP side:

```
if (!empty($_POST['defect']) && count($_POST['defect']) > 1) {
    // all ok
} else {
    // show error
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't take into account that $_POST['defect'] might not be an array. Applying count a variable that is not an array will return TRUE. The user would then assume they can loop through an array that isn't there and get a "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in" warning.  In addition, the user requests that at least 1 checkbox needs to be checked yet the code above says there must be more than one checked.